# Documenting COM object with doxygen: how to document class members without documenting class

Tags: c++, com, doxygen, member-functions

I use doxygen to generate two sets of documentation for my C++ COM object (an .OCX file): a full documentation for programmers, and a "user documentation" for those who use my object in VB. The user docs should only contain the exported functions. All exported functions are members of the main "Ctrl" class. This class shall not be included in the user docs, but only its members. How do I achieve that with doxygen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround:

Define modules with `\defgroup`, put them around the declarations of the exported functions, leave the main `Ctrl` class undocumented, and set the doxygen options "HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES" and "HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES".